# What do we do with unmotivated student questions?

Tags: discussion

There has been [considerable discussion](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems) in the SO community regarding what to do with low-quality, zero-effort questions about homework.  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40159338/need-help-for-school) is a classic example, a question titled *Need help for school*, with the entire question as follows:

> User enters how many random numbers to be displayed. Those random numbers will then be converted to binary. After showing the binary numbers, it will then show how many 1s are there in each binary.
>
> (C PROGRAMMING)

With all due kindness and respect, I find myself sorely tempted to answer with "give your teacher a hard kick in the leg", or "early civilizations had no concept of zero".  Very funny, but what would be a truly helpful thing to say?

How about "change your major"?

I'm serious.  Questions like this indicate that the asker is unlikely to ever be an effective programmer who enjoys his work.  Why waste time and money "learning" something you neither enjoy nor do well?

I bet most programmers can remember their first-ever program, and the moment when "the lights came on".  For me, it was when I was 14.  I had a little book about programming in BASIC, and I wrote something like this:

```
10 PRINT "What is your name"
20 INPUT A$
30 PRINT "Hello, ";A$
RUN
```

It worked!  It did what I said!  I was hooked!  I bought an Atari 400 and spent many a happy hour writing video games, screen savers, and whatnot.  After years of programming as an on-again, off-again hobby, I finally got hired into a real software shop, and I've been a pro now for about 18 years.

One reason my own education has been reasonably successful is, I've worked on problems that I cared about and found interesting, often as an amateur with no motivation other than the intrinsic interest of the problem.  The exercise in the question above is trivial and pointless.  The main (for some people the only) motivation to work on it is that it is a homework assignment in a class that costs money.  I think both the school and the student are making a mistake.

I never went to school to learn programming.  If I had, I'd probably be a better programmer than I am.  Certainly I've worked with people who had bachelor's degrees and superior skills.  But I've also met college-graduate "programmers" who were intimidated by the prospect of installing an Ubuntu system.  Apparently these people got through school with someone holding their hand the whole time.

That's a tragedy and a crime.  A programmer's education is never complete.  The ability to independently study and learn is crucial; you have to keep up with changes in the software business, new languages and paradigms, etc.  If you stop learning when they kick you out of school, you won't be worth much in the market, and you'll have to find some dead-end other job so you can service your college debt.

The person who asked the above question presumably has access to reference materials, lectures, Stack Overflow, google, etc.  But they can't get a handle on a trivial problem.  Their first response to a challenge is to look for someone to hold their hand.  Can schooling really inculcate the critical self-teaching skills this person needs?  Considering what college costs, is it worth the gamble?  What is the failure rate of students like this?  (I assume at least some of them must improve, but I've no idea how likely that is.)

My guess is, programmers who are successful in school and beyond already have "the lights on" when they show up for class the first day, or very shortly thereafter.  They've picked up a little programming (or maybe a lot) in their spare time already.  They can conceptualize at least a simple program and do their own research on details of syntax etc.  They're not easily intimidated or discouraged.  Even if the work is pointless, they at least increase their bags-of-tricks with each exercise, and trivial work doesn't cost them much time or worry because they can blast through it.

What can you say to someone who obviously isn't like that?  The school promises a level of success that is unlikely to manifest.  The student expects to cheat and win.  So the dishonesty is mutual, but the student is the one whose time, money, and life prospects are wasted.

Stack Overflow is not a career-counseling site, so "change your major / drop out" is not an on-topic response.  But I've been tempted more than once.

Is there a sensible, responsible, not-too-unkind way to suggest that a student like this should get out before they get hurt?  Are there situations where that kind of response would benefit SO and the wider community?

Comment: `Is there a sensible, responsible, not-too-unkind way to suggest that a student like this should get out before they get hurt? Are there situations where that kind of response would benefit SO and the wider community?` No and no, I think. SO is not the right place for this kind of advice, and we're not the right people to give it (because we're just random folks on an anonymous platform that isn't about that kind of advice.)

Comment: *I bet most programmers can remember their first-ever program, and the moment when "the lights came on".* what am I even reading

Comment: You are reading a metaphor, Will.  When you write your first program, or discover web sockets or a graphics library or a new language or paradigm or whatever, "the lights come on".  There's a sudden feeling of enlightenment and power, an awareness of new creative potentials.  Not everyone gets this experience from programming, and some might benefit from seeking it elsewhere.  When I see incoherent code and people getting stumped on trivial problems, I think the lights are not on.  Note that I've accepted Makoto's answer and I won't be pressing this issue in the main forum.

Comment: "These people don't care how you react; they're looking for the one guy that will actually do their homework for them (some people will)..." ([Robert Harvey](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/3837/31260))

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You're overthinking this.  Especially considering that we get these kinds of questions from *professional* developers, there's no reason to single out just students.

Here's the key takeaway you should have from these kinds of questions:

## You don't need to say a *word*.

Chances are very good that they're not going to listen to you anyway.

Simply downvote and close these questions accordingly.  No further commentary is necessary, and once they start to realize that they can't just get someone to write their code for them on Stack Overflow - *especially* after the question ban hits - then they'll either learn to stand up on their own and do their own work, or they'll depart the field.

Answer (score 4):

I used to make comments, based on the flag --> close wording, but found that was a waste of time. Taking time away from reading other potentially interesting content, or being able to provide an answer to a far better written question.

Just downvote (if you can), flag and move on.

Comment: I concur with the down vote response to unmotivated student questions. I am also inclined to ask the student to append what work they have done so far on trying to resolve their homework problem. One person can add this brief comment and others can click the comment's up arrow to offer further encouragement. The truly unmotivated students will have done nothing and will have nothing to append, thus inviting more down votes for the original question.